# How to pass the variable of the result of find command to dd

Tags: environment-variables, find, dd

I'm trying to transfer CentOS.iso file to a USB flash drive using `dd` command by passing a variable which is a result of find command.

I want to pass variable like this

```
dd if=$isofile of=/dev/sdb
```

First I need to create a proper variable, so this is how I do it

```
isofile='find ~ -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso"'
```

However the output of executing the created variable

```
$isofile
```

doesn't look promising. I can't pass this to `dd if=` command.

[image: terminal window]

Is this possible to achieve? To pass variable to `if=`?

On the same note, would it be possible to pass the `find` command's result to `-exec dd {}` and transfer the `.iso` file that way?

Comment: Minor thing - assuming your isofile= command did work, you would view its contents with "echo $isofile", not $isofile - tha latter will try run the contents of $isofile, rather then display the variable.

Comment: After defining the variable with wrong ticks, running it was a semi-right thing to do to achieve *something*. It didn't find the file because `find -iname` got the argument with literal double quotes. In case of the command running "by hand" the shell used these quotes to know what to do (and what not to do) with the string inside, then passed the string to `find` without them.

Comment: Note: `dd if="$isofile" …` (quoting!) is better. Space in the filename won't break the command.

Comment: Yes Kamil, double quotes for variables, you will not see me doing this mistake again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong escape command.  The command you are issuing using a single enquote character basically defines your whole find string as a string of letters.  (You can see this by typing echo $isofile).   What you want to do is execute this and then make the output into a variable.   There are at least 2 ways to do this -

The way you probably intended to - which is to use backticks rather then forward ticks, ie

```
  isofile=`find /home/tomas -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso"`
```

or a similar, more modern version

```
  isofile=$( find /home/tomas -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso" )
```

Both of the above have the problem of what if there is more then 1 file matching.   You can fix this by doing something like the below to take the first line.

```
 isofile=$( find /home/tomas -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso" | head -1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

[davidgo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325711/432690) doesn't address the last part. Let me.

> would it be possible to pass the `find` command's result to `-exec dd {}` and transfer the `.iso` file that way?

Yes. Your first approach may be:

```
find ~ -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso" -exec dd if={} of=/dev/sdb \;
```

however this will sequentially run more than one `dd` if there is more than one matching file. In effect all but the last `dd` will be a waste of time. To ensure `find` stops after the first successful `dd` use `-quit`:

```
find ~ -iname "*centos*minimal*.iso" -exec dd if={} of=/dev/sdb \; -quit
```

Note `-quit` is not required by POSIX, your `find` may or may not support it.

Comment: Thank you Kamil for not closing your eyes on to the second part as it was as important important for me as the first part of the question.